# Check network connection in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, mobile

Can I check in a mobile web page if the user is using a data plan or Wi-fi? Is there any way to do this, even with proprietary API?

Comment: Not sure if [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MozMobileConnection.data) applies...

Comment: Something like that would be nice, but unfortunately that one is available only on Firefox OS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be accessed like this

```
(navigator.connection || navigator.mozConnection || navigator.webkitConnection).type
```

where type can be one of "cellular", "bluetooth", "ethernet", "wifi", "wimax", "other", "none", "mixed", "unknown" (see https://w3c.github.io/netinfo/#the-connectiontype-enum for more details).

Unfortunately the [support](http://caniuse.com/#search=Network%20Information%20API) is pretty scarse. It is [supported in Phonegap](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-network-information).